# .dismiss() is showing an error in AlertDialog

Tags: java, android, android-alertdialog

I have the following code:

```
            AlertDialog.Builder b = new AlertDialog.Builder(getActivity());
            View view = LayoutInflater.from(getActivity()).inflate(R.layout.displayfilecontents, null);
            EditText text = (EditText) view.findViewById(R.id.etFileContents);
            if (text != null) {
                text.setFocusable(false);
                text.setLongClickable(false);
                text.setTextIsSelectable(false);
            }
            text.setText(builder);
            b.setView(view);
            b.setTitle("Trip Name: " + FilesInFolder.get(position).toString().substring(0, FilesInFolder.get(position).toString().lastIndexOf(".")));
            Button btnCloseIt = (Button) view.findViewById(R.id.btnClose);
            btnCloseIt.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                public void onClick(View v) {
                    b.dismiss();
                }
            });
            AlertDialog dl = b.create();
            dl.show();
```

I am trying to dismiss the dialog once the `btnCloseIt` is pressed. I am receiving an error on this line:

```
b.dismiss(); //giving an error
```

Error: `The method dismiss() is undefined for the type AlertDialog.Builder`

**Update**: [**RESOLVED**]

```
        // custom dialog
        final Dialog dialog = new Dialog(getActivity());
        dialog.setContentView(R.layout.displayfilecontents);
        dialog.setTitle("Trip Name: " + FilesInFolder.get(position).toString().substring(0, FilesInFolder.get(position).toString().lastIndexOf(".")));

        EditText text = (EditText) dialog.findViewById(R.id.etFileContents);
        if (text != null) {
            text.setFocusable(false);
            text.setLongClickable(false);
            text.setTextIsSelectable(false);
        }
        text.setText(builder);
        Button btnCloseIt = (Button) dialog.findViewById(R.id.btnClose);
        // if button is clicked, close the custom dialog
        btnCloseIt.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            public void onClick(View v) {
                dialog.dismiss();
            }
        });
        dialog.show();
```

Comment: When you call b.create() you are returned an AlertDialog. Save a reference to that AlertDialog dialog = b.create(); . Then call dialog.show(). Then you may call dialog.dismiss();

Comment: Where do I call the button listener method than?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As others have already pointed out, `b` is a reference to `AlertDialog.Builder` and not to the `Dialog` itself. `AlertDialog.Builder` class doesn't have any method named `dismiss()`. Save a reference to the `Dialog` which is returned to you when you call `create()` or `show()` method from `AlertDialog.Builder` class.

One more thing, since you are calling `create()` and `show()` methods at the same time, do you really want to call both the methods? I believe calling only `show()` method would suffice for you here. From Developer Reference [public AlertDialog show () : Creates a AlertDialog with the arguments supplied to this builder and show()'s the dialog.](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/AlertDialog.Builder.html#show%28%29)

Comment: If you put it like that, it makes sense. Let me work on it and update everyone.

Answer (score 1):

You need to store the result of calling `b.create()`; that's what you need to call `dismiss()` on.